# Append Array and replace Keys in JSON object

Tags: java, arrays, json

How we have append `Array` and replace `Keys` functions in `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` with an ease?

**Example:**

```
JsonObject a = new JsonObject().put("a", new JsonArray().add(2)).put("b", "hello");
JsonObject b = new JsonObject().put("a", new JsonArray().add(3)).put("b", "hi");
```

**Expected result:**

```
{"a": [2, 3], "b": "hi"}
```

If I do `a.mergeIn(b, true)`, it results: `{"a": [3], "b": "hi"}`.

And in general, `merge` function appends array value or it replaces the value in the case of `Array`?